# How do I do conversion tracking across sites?

Tags: google-analytics, conversions, click-tracking

I have two sites, a website and a web application. Both the site and the application uses the same Google Analytics tracking code, and I then use filters to show data for the site and the app.

I am now not certain, how I can do conversion tracking. I would like to track a user who clicks a signup button on the website, which takes you to the signup form on the application, and track how many actually signup.

So basically so I can track e.g. my AdWords on how many actually signup. How could this be done, across the site and web application?

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you should use other tracking codes for the app and the site
2. you could create a filtered views for app and website - make life easier
3. to track which signup is from app, you could add a dimension e.g. Mobile Device Info (ga:mobileDeviceInfo), app version (ga:appVersion)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use same tracking code for both Website & web application.
2. For Conversion tracking use destination URL of your Signup form.